# Conditional subtraction

Tags: r, conditional-statements, multiplication

I have a big data.frame (TOTAL) with some values (cols11-16) that I need to subtract a base from which is multiplied by a value depending on two conditions in TOTAL.

The data.frame (TOTAL) looks a little like this

```
Channel    Hour      Category cols11 cols12 cols13 cols14 cols15 base
TV1        04:00:00  New      2      5      4      5      6      2,4
TV5        05:00:00  Old      1      5      3      9      7      1,8
TV1        03:00:00  New      8      7      9      2      4      5,4
```

There are 4 different channels, and 24 different hours (00:00:00-23:00:00)

I have four other vectors with the conditionedvariable that needs to be multiplied on the base depending on the Hour and the Channel,
So for each channel I have a vector like this:

```
TV1Slope:
TV1Slope00 TV1Slope01 TV1Slope02.. TV1Slope23
0,0012      0,0015    0,013       0,0009


TOTAL$Uplift0 <- (TOTAL$cols11 - TOTAL$base * conditionedvariable)
TOTAL$Uplift1 <- (TOTAL$cols12 - TOTAL$base * conditionedvariable)
TOTAL$Uplift2 <- (TOTAL$cols13 - TOTAL$base * conditionedvariable)
TOTAL$Uplift3 <- (TOTAL$cols14 - TOTAL$base * conditionedvariable)
TOTAL$Uplift4 <- (TOTAL$cols15 - TOTAL$base * conditionedvariable)
```

How do I make R choose the conditioned variable based on the conditions?

Comment: It is not clear.  Which one is the `conditionedvariable`?  Also, not sure whether the `base` values are character vectors or not (based on `,` ).  If the `,` is a decimal, you can read the dataset specifying `dec=','` in `read.table/read.csv`  Your statement `multipled on the base depending on the Hour and the Channel` is not clear.  What are the conditions?

Comment: Yes the "," is a decimal (Forgot the differences in decimals depending on origin)

The conditionedvariable is the variable that is taken from the 4 vectors depending on what channel it is, and what hour it is.

So I need it to look up the row's Channel and Hour, to determine what the conditionedvariable has to be

Comment: You may need to provide a reproducible example with expected output.  In the current state, it is not clear about the conditions

Comment: There wasnt enough space, so I created a new post.

Find it here: 
http:// stackoverflow.com/ questions/30735180/conditional-subtraction-part-2